# Setting Autofac dependency resolver causes 'access to security critical type ILifeTimeScope failed' exception

Tags: c#, .net, security, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to auto inject some component of my solution in a web api controller and using autofac to do this.

For this I'm doing the following in the Global.asax.cs:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(ModuleFramework.Container));
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(ModuleFramework.Container);
```

However, when I try to set the autofac dependency resolver, I get the following error:

```
Attempt by security transparent method 

'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RequestLifetimeScopeProvider..ctor(Autofac.ILifetimeScope)' to access security critical type 'Autofac.ILifetimeScope' failed.

Assembly 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' is marked with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception.
```

After some searching online, I see a couple of posts where they recommend to reinstall the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost`, but unfortunately this doesn't work in my case.  Can anybody explain to me what the core issue is right here and maybe which steps to take on how to resolve this?